# pyqt move widget in x axis only

Tags: python, pyqt5, widget

I'm working with `PyQt5` and I'm trying to center a label horizontally. The label is already loaded from a gui file using Qt Designer. I want to know how I can use the `move` method to update only the x axis, without changing the y axis.

```
class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.h_center(self.label)
        ...
   
    def h_center(widget):
        screen_width = self.frameGeometry().width()
        widget_width = widget.width()
        widget.move((screen_width - widget_width) / 2, 20)
```

As you can see I have to give a the y axis a value of 20, which overrides the default value that I set using the designer. if I ignore it I get the following error :

```
>>> widget.move((screen_width - widget_width) / 2)
>>> move(self, QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
>>> move(self, int, int): not enough arguments
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you're doing this because you're using *fixed geometries* in your UI and you cannot/don't want to use layout managers? If that's so, may I ask you why?

Comment: It's the first time I use PyQt and I have no background on code based gui. So in my case using the designer is helpful.

Comment: That was not what I asked. If you want widgets that automatically adapt to their parent, you must use layout managers, which automatically take care of everything, including size restrains, minimum size requirements, etc. You can read more about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and how to use them [in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Using fixed geometries is 99% of times a *bad* choice, as you cannot just rely on what you see on your screen, and for complex interfaces it easily makes your UI unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the value of the y-axis then you must set that previous value:

```py
y = widget.pos().y()
widget.move((screen_width - widget_width) / 2, y)
```

or

```py
widget.move((screen_width - widget_width) / 2, widget.y())
```

Comment: Or even `widget.move((screen_width - widget_width) / 2, widget.y())`